# digest method cant be used solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, cryptojs

I've been getting an error while using Crypto.js and couldn't figure out why.
I tried to use the createHash.update.digest methods.
After some time I realized that I had a typo but the error that have been thrown was incorrect.
the error was:

"digest method cant be used"

My code was:

```
this.passwordResetToken = crypto.createHash('sh256').update(resetToken).digest('hex');
```

The solution to the error was changing the createHash algorithm to the currect one without the typo:

```
this.passwordResetToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex');
```

I had a missing 'a' in the algorithm name. Why is the error saying "digest method cant be used" when I have made a typo?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: It's not a question, I'm just trying to post my solution to anybody that will get the same error, search for a solution and not find anything helpful.

Comment: If it was just the question part (without the solution), the question would have been closed as *"Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"*.

Comment: If you want to share information that way, you still have to post a question, and then write your own answer to your question (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). But, as stated earlier, the question would just be closed as "caused by a typo".

Comment: This is an answer to a problem the user faced, not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the behavior you experienced is that the parameter specified for `createHash` specifies the digest method. Since you have provided an invalid digest method (because of your typo), the tool checked whether that digest method is available and found that it is not, hence you received this error.